# sprintf and array of char vs std::string

Tags: c++

I'm wondering why given the following:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[50];
    //char str1[] = "ahoy";
    //char str2[] = "matey";
    std::string str1 = "ahoy";
    std::string str2 = "matey";

    sprintf(buf, "%s %s\n", str1, str2);

    std::cout << buf;
    return 0;
}
```

When str1, str2 are the array of characters, I get the expected output of `ahoy matey`.  But when str1, str2, are std::string, I get jarbled output.  Does it have to do with the fact that the char array is literally just that and std::string might have some metadata before the actually char array?

Comment: what's the compile warning?

Comment: In C++ normally you'd use a stringstream for this type of operation instead of sprintf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much got it right. An `std::string` contains extra information besides the string itself, such as the length of the string. In fact, the characters aren't actually stored in the string object. Instead, the string object stores a memory address of the characters, which are somewhere else.

If you need to use a function that takes a char array, use the [`c_str` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). You can't modify what this function returns though, and the result could be invalidated if the string object changes.

C input/output functions know nothing about the C++ strings and try to interpret the data as a char array, which is why you get garbage. If you turn on your compiler warnings (which you really should do), the compiler will warn you about this.

You should just stick with C++ strings and input/output. `std::string` provides a handy [overload for the `+` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) that concatenates strings. Use this if you aren't immediately outputting the result.

```
newString = str1 + ' ' + str2;
```

You can also just use multiple `<<`s, which can prevent stuff like extra copying that happens when you use `+`.

```
std::cout << str1 << ' ' << str2 << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will give a warning:

> ```
> prog.cc:15:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*',
> but argument 3 has type 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka
> 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} [-Wformat=]
>
>  sprintf(buf, "%s %s\n", str1, str2);
>               ^~~~~~~~~
> ```

Since [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf):

```
int sprintf( char* buffer, const char* format, ... );
```

expects `char* args`.

Thus, if you really want to use `std::string` convert it first to **c-string**.

```
sprintf(buf, "%s %s\n", str1.c_str(), str2.c_str());
```

**C++-ish**

Other way is using `stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << str1 << " " << str2;
std::cout << ss.str(); // ahoy matey
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:
 `sprintf(buf, "%s %s\n", str1.c_str(), str2.c_str());` Otherwise you're going to get the raw class data -- clearly not what you wanted. However, don't mix C and C++ like that. Use `std::string` all the way. IOW, consider a `stringstream` for your append instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you say,

```
sprintf(buf, "%s %s\n", str1, str2);
```

`%s` format specifier expects a pointer to the initial element of an array of characters whereas `str1` and `str2` are `std::string`

[The warning tells it all](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hFXDk8jTXFpJLnl9)